# autocomplete on input field created with jquery after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-after

I have a field on which an autocomplete function is implemented. This is my code :

```
<%= f.text_field :auteur_1, size: 100, class:"champs_auteur", data: {autocomplete_source: auteurs_enum_path} %>
```

That creates the following html :

```
<input size="100" class="champs_auteur ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete-source="/auteurs/enum" name="biblio[auteur_1]" id="biblio_auteur_1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

And this is in my javascript :

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  return $('.champs_auteur').autocomplete({
    source: $('.champs_auteur').data('autocomplete-source')
  });
});
```

All that works fine. I am creating input fields using jquery `after()` and `append()`, like this :

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    i = 2 ;
    $(".extra_auteur").click(function(){
        $('.premier_auteur').after('<div class="grid mbm"><div class="one-sixth"><label for="biblio_auteur">Auteur</label></div><input size="100" class="champs_auteur" data-autocomplete-source="/auteurs/enum" type="text" name="biblio[auteur_' + i++ + ']" id="biblio_auteur_1" /></div>');
        });
  });
```

This is minified code (mainly html) for :

```
<div class="grid mbm">
    <div class="one-sixth">
        <label for="biblio_auteur">Auteur</label>
    </div>
    <input size="100" class="champs_auteur" data-autocomplete-source="/auteurs/enum" type="text" name="biblio[auteur_' + i++ + ']" id="biblio_auteur_1" />
</div>
```

This does create the input field with an `id="biblio_auteur_2"` (and 3, 4 etc...).

The autocomplete doesn't work on the additional input fields. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using the element #ID instead of the class-name as in:

```
$( "#aut_extra" )
```

And #ID is always unique, and will therefore only work for 1 item. What yu need to do is have the jQuery select the CSS element class instead and not ID.

```
$( ".aut_extra" )
```

or whatever the class name is.

But you must be sure that the element which currently have the ID of aut_extra instead have a CSS class with the same name.

```
<div class="aut_extra"....
```

Comment: Thanks Crashtor. I am selecting the CSS element class `class="champs_auteur`  The id `.aut_extra` exists to `append()`, not to ` autocomplete()`.

Comment: If the  "#aut_extra" is an ID of "champs_auteur", then just use $( ".champs_auteur" ) instead of $( ".aut_extra" ) on line 6. But you must use a CSS class on line 5 and 6 and NOT ID's - if you want it to work for multiple fields on the same page.

Comment: "#aut_extra# is not an ID of "champs_auteur". I did clean up the code according to your advice and I'll update the question to reflect the code.

Answer (score 1):

Crashtor is correct, page ids MUST be unique for proper functioning.  However, you might have another issue.  You're calling autocomplete during document ready, but when you change the dom by adding new fields, those existed after the autocomplete function was initialized.

Try calling autocomplete on each after append.

```
$('.extra_amatur:last').find('input[type=text]:last').autocomplete({
     source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')
});
```

Comment: Thanks trh ! I understand the idea, but this code doesn't work (yet). I get no error, console is empty, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your help. Both errors needed to be corrected, the first on that only classes should be used and the second that the autocomplete should be used on another event then document ready. I took on click.

This is the code (if this could ever help someone) :

```
$(document).on('click', '.champs_2_auteur', function() {
    return $('.champs_2_auteur').autocomplete({
        source: $('.champs_2_auteur').data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you - then you should accept your own answer. That is a message to the community that this is a functioning answer.

Comment: I tried to do that but I "can't vote for my own post". Should I edit my initial question and then accept ?

Comment: There's a greyed out check mark below the up and down voting arrows ( to the left of the answer) -- is that not clickable?  That's the answer accept button.